# Replace elements of a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate `variablize/3` that takes a list and replaces each item, in turn, with a variable, example:

```
% ?- variablize([a,b,c], X, L).
% L = [[X, b, c], [a, X, c], [a, b, X]]
```

Now I am trying to extend this predicate to accept a list of variables, example:

```
% ?- variablize([a,b,c], [X,Y], L).
% L = [[X, Y, c], [X, b, Y], [a, X, Y]]
```

My code so far is:

```
replace_at([_|Tail], X, 1, [X|Tail]).
replace_at([Head|Tail], X, N, [Head|R]) :- M is N - 1, replace_at(Tail, X, M, R).

replace_each([], _, _, [], _).
replace_each([_|Next], Orig, X, [Res|L], N) :-
    replace_at(Orig, X, N, Res),
    M is N + 1,
    replace_each(Next, Orig, X, L, M).

variablize(I, X, L) :- replace_each(I, I, X, L, 1).
```

Any pointers? Do I extend `replace_at/4` to have a list of indexes that should be skipped?

Comment: It is very unusual to write a predicate where nonvariable terms are replaced by variables. Can you explain why you need this? Most of the time it is much more effective to construct terms the other way round.

Comment: @false I use it for basic NLP. A user can type a 'variable' ('[employees, of, acme]') instead of a term from the model ('[employees, of, company]') and so I can suggest what 'type' the word is for a search over a database index. I am a beginner at this so I am not doing anything stupid am I?

Comment: It does make some sense in your context. Nevertheless, you will have to have a lot of `var/1` `nonvar/1` tests in your programs. And you could (maybe) avoid some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplified, builtin based way of implementing `variablize`/3

```
variablize(I, X, L) :-
    bagof(R, U^select(U, I, X, R), L).
```

put in evidence that instead of [select](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/4)/4 we could have a distribute/3 that applies replacements of elements of X, when X becomes a list. select/4 can be implemented in this way

```
myselect(B, I, X, R) :-
    append(A, [B|C], I), append(A, [X|C], R).
```

and this form is convenient because we have the part to the right of input list `I`, where I suppose you need to distribute remaining variables. Then a recursion on `X` elements should do:

```
distribute(I, [X|Xs], L) :-
    append(A, [_|C], I),
    distribute(C, Xs, R),
    append(A, [X|R], L).
distribute(I, [], I).
```

distribute/3 behaves this way:

```
?- distribute([a,b,c,d],[1,2],X).
X = [1, 2, c, d] ;
X = [1, b, 2, d] ;
X = [1, b, c, 2] ;
X = [a, 1, 2, d] ;
X = [a, 1, c, 2] ;
X = [a, b, 1, 2] ;
false.
```

thus

```
variablize_l(I, X, L) :-
    bagof(R, distribute(I, X, R), L).
```

give us:

```
?- variablize_l([a,b,c],[X,Y],L).
L = [[X, Y, c], [X, b, Y], [a, X, Y]].
```

**edit**

I initially wrote this way, for here the evidence of separating the distribution phase from list construction:

```
replace_v([_|T], X, [X|T]).
replace_v([L|T], X, [L|R]) :-
    replace_v(T, X, R).
variablize(I, X, L) :-
    bagof(E, replace_v(I, X, E), L).
```

Comment: Thank you @chac! I will study distribute/3 some more and use write/1 to output all of the tree in Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

```
variablize(L1,L2,L) :-
    append(L1,L2,L3),
    length(L1,Len1),
    length(L2,Len2),
    findall(L4,(combination(L3,Len1,L4),var_count(L4,Len2)),L).

combination(X,1,[A]) :-
    member(A,X).
combination([A|Y],N,[A|X]) :-
    N > 1,
    M is N - 1,
    combination(Y,M,X).
combination([_|Y],N,A) :-
    N > 1,
    combination(Y,N,A).

var_count([],0).
var_count([V|R],N) :-
    var(V),
    var_count(R,N1),
    N is N1 + 1,
    !.
var_count([A|R],N) :-
    var_count(R,N).
```